# How do i split a string wherever there are digits?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of strings in a panda dataframe that i want to split keeping only the text.

Here is an example of what is in one string:
'Eliminate render-blocking resources 0.46s Serve images in next-gen formats 0.45s Reduce server response times (TTFB) 0.22s Remove unused CSS 0.15s'

Here is what i would like to get in different columns:
['Eliminate render-blocking resources', 'Serve images in next-gen formats', 'Reduce server response times (TTFB)', 'Remove unused CSS']

I thought of using the .str.split command  for '.' plus 3 characters to the right and one character to the left...but to be honest i don't know where to start.

Thanks for the help

Comment: A bit of a hack would be to use re.sub to convert all digits to the number 0, and then use str.split('0')

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression along with `re.split()`

```
import re

re.split(r'\d\.\d+s', your_string)
```

`\d\.\d+` would match any string like `0.15s`, 0.22s etc. 
Example:

```
s = 'Eliminate render-blocking resources 0.46s Serve images in next-gen formats 0.45s Reduce server response times (TTFB) 0.22s Remove unused CSS 0.15s'
re.split('\d\.\d+s', s)
['Eliminate render-blocking resources ', ' Serve images in next-gen formats ', ' Reduce server response times (TTFB) ', ' Remove unused CSS ', '']
```

After this you can use remove the trailing spaces & empty strings.

Comment: That brought me some steps forward and i am now trying to do that in my data frame. I saw that i can use .compile so i did the following (opportunities[1] is the column in the data frame where verything will have to be splitted).

`regex_pat = re.compile(r'\d\.\d+s', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
oppoerunitiesM = opportunities[1].str.split(regex_pat)
TypeError: object of type 're.Pattern' has no len() `

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Series.str.split` in combination with regex here. We also pass the argument `expand=True` so it returns a new column for every split:

```
df['Col'].str.split(r'[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}s', expand=True)
```

**Output**

```
                                      0                                   1                                      2                    3 4
0  Eliminate render-blocking resources    Serve images in next-gen formats    Reduce server response times (TTFB)    Remove unused CSS
```

Comment: That really seems what i needed! I tried but it splits the cell only if i remove the s like this: `(r'[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}', expand=True)`. As a result i keep the s at the beginning of the new cell and i really would like to remove it.